# What alternate methods we can use for notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a problem. What I want to do is, I  just want to display a message in notification bar at frequent time of interval. For that I used two notification methods they are:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
 ......
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
```

Currently I am using API level 19. So I came to know above ones are deprecated. I was suggested to use Notification.builder. But after using that I am not getting proper output. Can anyone show me the code how to use Notification.Builder for above 2 statements...
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this...

```
public static void createNotification(Context context, Long data) {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i = rnd.nextInt();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Logo").setContentText("text");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, activity.class);

        resultIntent.putExtra(StringUtils.SESSIONID, data);
        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for
        // the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(activity.class);
//      stackBuilder.editIntentAt(index);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: NotificationCompact.Builder is for lower API levels. How we can use Notification.Builder for above statements(which are in question)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setSubText(subTitle)
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
         .build();
```

This is example is from here: [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

To set the time you could use the method `setWhen(long timestamp);`

Comment: yeah I tried this example but how to use that for second statement?

Comment: see my edited answer: you set the title with `setContentTitle`, then set the subtitle using `setSubText` then you set the pending intent `setContentIntent`, the context was sent through the constructor parameter

Comment: The first statement was working fine. In second statement can we use notification directly to use above methods?

Comment: as far as i understand from the documentation, yes you could do that

Comment: what I am asking is..How to use Notification.Builder for notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent); statement? I could not use .set methods directly with notification instance can you help me in that?